# Activities and Resources in a separate assembly, referencing app cannot find the resources

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I created a small application that had an Activity that returns a result.

The activity relies on a custom Adapter and a few .axml resources.

Once the application was up and running,
I tried moving that activity including
all resources to a separate Android library project.

I'm now able to compile the separate project, but as soon as I reference it
from the main application, the main application no longer compiles
 because it 
cannot find the recourses of the separate project,
even though the main application doesn't use those resources.

> 'Example.App.Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for
>   Magnify  in 
> 'Example.App.Resource.Drawable' does not contain a
>   definition for DeviceListItem
> etc...

These errors occur in Resource.Designer.cs

My idea is to have the Activity (and the resources it requires)
in a separate project/assembly so I can use it again in other projects.

The errors occur even when I create a blank android application and reference the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving resources into subprojects hasn't been supported very long. (It wasn't supported traditionally in Java Android projects either)

Right now the support is very early stage.

If you want to try it, then there is some good knowledge in http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1435/troubles-using-resources-from-library-project

But overall, I'd suggest you wait - I don't think it's quite reached Stable release quality today.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, as I noticed some projects on GitHub that provide 'controls' but are always part of the main app. In that case I will simply include it in my main app for now. Thank you for clearing it up!

Comment: The future is close - but it's not quite there!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a project and I needed to put all `drawables`, `layouts`, etc in a separate DLL to match the architecture of my solution on iOS and on Windows. I had trouble getting it to work on Android but I finally did get it to work. Things to watch out for.

1. Your `Drawables`, `Layouts`, etc all need to be `lower-case`.
2. Ensure that your class library (dll) is targeting `Android 4.0`.
3. Ensure that there is no multiple resources (`images`, `layouts`, etc) that has the same name. Not even in a different library.
4. Ensure that your Main App project is referencing your external project that has these resources.

If you do all the above, it should work fine. Hope it helps somebody else. And thanks Stuart for the link, learned a lot from that :)

Comment: You might also need to force the updating of the Resource Id values. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139479/resource-layout-filename-is-returning-the-wrong-layout-file/17140202#17140202