# Resource.Layout.filename is returning the wrong layout file

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I have a `MonoDroid` application project (let's call it `mainApp`). This references `app.Screen` project, which is a MFA library project. Initially, my activities were in the `mainApp` project. Everything was working fine. I needed to put some Activities (and resource, drawables, etc) in the `app.Screen` project. 
I have moved all the resources I need to the `app.Screen` project. It builds fine and in my activities (which are sitting in app.screens) I can access `Resource.Layout.filename` and even `Layout.Id.name`.

However, when I run the application, in `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.filename)` I get the **wrong layout file** . This causes `FindById<Button>()` to return `null` obviously because it does not have these buttons in this layout file.

I found that same Layout file has different Id in my MFA library project than what is in the mainApp project like this:

```
// In the mainApp project
public partial class Layout
{
    // aapt resource value: 0x7f030001
    public const int DeliveryScreenLayout = 2130903041;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f03000a
    public const int splash_screen_layout = 2130903050;

    private Layout()
    {
    }
}

// in app.screen library project
public partial class Layout
{

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f030000
    public static int has_hello_layout = 2130903040;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f030001
    public static int splash_screen_layout = 2130903041;

    private Layout()
    {
    }
}
```

I am using VS 2010 with MFA 4.0 and my projects are targeting Android 4.0. I have tried `Clean & Build`, Removing `/Bin` and `/Obj` folder, with no luck.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug in `MonoDroid`, here is the [link to the bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12713) in Xamarin bugzilla

This is caused by the `Resource.Designer.cs` in the MFA library project has a **different ID (int) values** than what the main project has in its `Resource.Designer.cs` file.

I have worked out a workaround for it. In my `mainApp` I manually call `mainApp.Resources.UpdateIdValues();` and that would update the `Resources` id values in the other MFA library projects

Xamarin said that this bug was resolved in 4.6.4. I have not tested this fix though